# Android WebViewClient - Load follow redirect after Login (Joomla)

Tags: android, redirect, webview, webviewclient

I've built up a Joomla site and want this show/load in a WebView. After login in Joomla follows a redirect, this is not displayed in the WebView. Is there a simple way, you have an example perhaps?

```
public class MainActivityWebbrowser extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_webbrowser);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
            viewx.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(viewx, urlx);
        }
    });
    return;
}
```